# Returning promise from async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Can promise to be returned like below? Does the catch block return a promise or a normal Error?

```
async function beforeProcessing(ctx) {
  try {
      let res = await validateList(ctx)
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (res && res.length > 0) {
              const customErr = new Error(`missing for ${res} types`);
              customErr.statusCode = 422;
              reject(customErr);
          }
          else {
              resolve();
          }
      })
  } catch (error) {
      return new Error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: The function will always return a promise by dint of being marked `async`. Awaiting that promise will always result in a value, regardless of what the function returns. The `new Promise` inside the function is pointless.

Comment: with async: "if a promise is not returned, JavaScript automatically wraps it in a resolved promise with its value."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but there's no reason to. `async` functions *always* return promises. Just handle that logic inline, and throw `customErr` to reject the function's promise:

```
async function beforeProcessing(ctx) {
    let res;
    try {
        res = await validateList(ctx)
    } catch (error) {
        return new Error(error); // *** This is highly suspect
    }
    if (res && res.length > 0) {
        const customErr = new Error(`missing for ${res} types`);
        customErr.statusCode = 422;
        throw customErr;
    }
}
```

But as I mentioned in a comment above, *returning* an error object is highly suspect, it *fulfills* the promise with the error rather than rejecting the promise. Just let the error propagate to the caller (which will reject the `async` function's promise):

```
async function beforeProcessing(ctx) {
    let res = await validateList(ctx)
    if (res && res.length > 0) {
        const customErr = new Error(`missing for ${res} types`);
        customErr.statusCode = 422;
        throw customErr;
    }
}
```

Also, that `if` condition looks odd vs. the error message. The error message makes it look like the condition should be `<= 0`, not `> 0`, but of course I could be inferring incorrectly there.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in depth in Chapter 8, and `async`/`await` in Chapter 9, of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: condition is to throw an error if the res is `>0`. Thanks, TJ